# plupload destroys images

Tags: php, upload, plupload

Im using the plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php jquery widget - but some images (mainly jpegs over 1MB) get uploaded but I can not open them. Even when manually downloading them via ftp - they are corrupted/broken. Has anyone ever had a similar problem and knows how to fix this?

Edit: Images work before uploading them.

Using the code from the example:

```
$("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
    // General settings
    runtimes : 'flash,gears,silverlight,browserplus,html5',
    url : '../../upload.php',
    max_file_size : '6mb',
    chunk_size : '1mb',
    unique_names : true,

    // Specify what files to browse for
    filters : [
        {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"}
    ],

    // Flash settings
    flash_swf_url : '/assets/script/plupload/plupload.flash.swf',

    // Silverlight settings
    silverlight_xap_url : '/assets/script/plupload/plupload.silverlight.xap'

});



// Client side form validation
$('form#galerie_upload').submit(function(e) {
    var uploader = $('#uploader').pluploadQueue();

    // Files in queue upload them first
    if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
        // When all files are uploaded submit form
        uploader.bind('StateChanged', function() {
            if (uploader.files.length === (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
                $('form#galerie_upload')[0].submit();
            }
        });

        uploader.start();
    } else {
        alert('You must queue at least one file.');
    }

    return false;
});
```

upload.php is the example upload.php from [here](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/master/examples/upload.php)

Hope someone stumbled over this already.

have a nice day!

Comment: im having the same issue - when i work it out ill post

Comment: Can you please compare the original and the messed-up images byte-to-byte, and check what is the difference. Where is the difference, which is messed up by the uploader? Is it just the header, or the end of the file is truncated, or what happens exactly?

Comment: its working now for me - the error was in another script, that I forgot about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake was in another script, that cut the images after they had been uploaded.
Code as I posted it works!